# Grouping Values in a combination of List and Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Consider a dictionary in which the keys are integers and values are again dictionaries having two keys as follows:

```
servicesdict = { 0 : {'cost' : 30, 'features' : ['f1']},
    1 : {'cost' : 50, 'features' : ['f1']},
    2 : {'cost' : 70, 'features' : ['f1']},
    3 : {'cost' : 200, 'features' : ['f1']},
    4 : {'cost' : 20, 'features': ['f2']},

    5 : {'cost' : 10, 'features' : ['f3']},
    6 : {'cost' : 20, 'features' : ['f3']},
    7 : {'cost' : 50, 'features' : ['f3']},
    8 : {'cost' : 70, 'features' : ['f3']},
    9 : {'cost' : 20, 'features' : ['f4']},

    10 : {'cost' : 20, 'features': ['f5']},
    11 : {'cost' : 20, 'features': ['f5']},
    12 : {'cost' : 40, 'features': ['f5']},
    }

    t1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
    t2 = [5,6,7,8,9]
    t3 = [10,11,12]
    task = [ t1, t2, t3]
```

We need to group the sublists in `task` according to the dictionary value of `features` and create a list where each sublist is numbered a consecutive value. I have written the following code to group these values according to 'features' which works correctly and produces the desired output:

```
tasknew = []
for t in task:
out = [[g for g in group] for key, group in itertools.groupby(t, key = lambda x:servicesdict[x]['features'])]
tasknew.append(out)


count = 0
newlist = []
for t in tasknew:
    x = dict()
    for c in t:
        x[count] = c
        count = count + 1
    newlist.append(x)
```

tasknew `[[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4]], [[5, 6, 7, 8], [9]], [[10, 11, 12]]]`

newlist
`[{0: [0, 1, 2, 3], 1: [4]}, {2: [5, 6, 7, 8], 3: [9]}, {4: [10, 11, 12]}]`

Is there a way to get the consecutive numbering using list or dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do this using a dictionary comprehension, and grouping the items in `tasks` according to the field `features` using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby, count
c = count()
newlist = [{next(c):list(v) for k,v in groupby(t, key= 
                             lambda x: servicesdict[x]['features'])} 
                             for t in task ]
```

---

```
print(new_list)

[{1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [4]},
 {3: [5, 6, 7, 8], 4: [9]},
 {5: [10, 11, 12]}]
```

---

And similarly for `tasknew`:

```
[[list(v) for k,v in groupby(t, key= 
          lambda x: servicesdict[x]['features'])] for t in task]
# [[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4]], [[5, 6, 7, 8], [9]], [[10, 11, 12]]]
```

Comment: This does not retain the groups like '1' and '2' should be in one group. In my original output, the keys 0 and 1 in the end output were grouped into one dictionary, this is not there in this

Comment: Got it, just realised. Updated the answer  @kauray

Comment: No way of numbering them from 0 to n ?

Comment: Well I was using the same  `features`, which seemed numbered. You can use `itertools.count`, check update @kauray

Comment: Is there a way to get the minimum cost in each group? Like for {1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [4]} the minimum cost value would be {1:30, 2:4}?

Comment: How are you computing the cost? @kauray

Comment: For 1: [0, 1, 2, 3] that would be the minimum cost of [0,1,2,3] from the servicesdict which is 30

Comment: `{k: min(v, key = lambda x:servicesdict[x]['cost']) for k, v in newlist.items()}` This produces the desired output on the newlist. Can this be done at one go?